# Jackson module deserializer not working after migration of spring from 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Before the migration we used a bean to initialize the serializer/deserializer in order to handle Timestamp -> LocalDateTime:

```
@Bean
Module dateModuleDeserialiser() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
        @Override
        public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            Long value = jsonParser.getLongValue();
            return new Timestamp(value).toLocalDateTime();
        }
    });

    return module;
}
```

Everything worked fine until we migrate Spring to 2.1.
We did what's marked here: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#with-spring-boot but now it is not working anymore.

If we put a breakpoint inside the deserializer we don't even pass on it... It is completely ignored.

Comment: Why would you reinvent the wheel, when Spring MVC and jackson does all the work for you already? You can use the proper annotations e.g. @JsonFormat

Comment: We don't want to set the @JsonFormat for each of our properties, it's redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found an other way to create `deserializer`/`serializer` with `Spring` and `Jackson`.

Instead of creating a `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` annotation for our `deserializer`/`serializer`, we created a new class with the annotation `@JsonComponent` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jackson/JsonComponent.html) and we put both of our `deserializer`/`serializer` in it. Everything works fine now.